# Route between VPN interface and alias interface

Tags: iptables, routing, vpn

I have the following setup:

```
     Windows PC     <--->       Raspberry Pi    <--->     PLC
 (DHCP - Ethernet)             (DHCP - eth0)
                         (192.168.0.10 - eth0:0)     (192.168.0.2)
(10.0.0.2 - VPN NIC)       (10.0.0.3 - VPN NIC)
```

The Raspberry Pi has only one ethernet port, so I had to setup **two IPs on the same port**: `eth0 - DHCP` (for accessing internet), `eth0:0 - 192.168.0.10` (for accessing the PLC). The alias eth0:0 was achieved by creating the file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0_0.conf` with the following:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.0.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

On the PLC, the IP was defined as `192.168.0.2`, and the gateway as `192.168.0.10`.

I want to be able to access the PLC directly from the Windows PC, using the Raspberry Pi only as a "bridge". The connection from the Windows PC to the Raspberry Pi is fully functional, and the connection between the Raspberry Pi and the PLC is too.

**What I have done**

On the Windows PC I ran the command `route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.3`

On the Raspberry PI I have edited `/etc/sysctl.conf` and made `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.
I ran `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.

I didn't work, so I also ran:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0:0 -o nrtap -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i nrtap -o eth0:0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sysctl -p
```

I also tried some variations of the above, but without success.

**Routing table:**

```
# route -nNv
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.3.254   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 nrtap
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

*nrtap is the VPN interface

Comment: @A.B No, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: @A.B Sorry. The port is not clearly identified, there is no setting for that in the PLC. As for the protocol or the broadcast, I don't have the slightest idea, those concepts are above my current level  of knowledge.
You think the major problem is the IPs sharing the interface? That it may not be possible to route/forward because of that?

Comment: Sure, I'll start trying to debug on Monday. I also got a USB-Ethernet adapter that is recognized by the Pi (eth1), and I'll try to route between eth0 and eth1, as having two real interfaces seems to be a more common situation, making finding information easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the VPN. I was using NeoRouter VPN, but found out that they do not support IP forwarding. Switched to ZeroTier VPN meanwhile, the setup was extremely simple and everything worked as intended on the first try.